# Security-tagged questions on SO/SF

Tags: discussion

There are some really great security questions asked on Stack Overflow / Superuser sites, with some really excellent answers. Had this site been around back then, here would have been a much more natural place for it.
Should we migrate those questions to here, in order to consolidate? Just copy the core points over? Or leave them there, since obviously they were on-topic originally...

My thought being that this site should eventually be the central repository for security information...

Comment: At some point we may want to add a comment to tagged questions directing people to this site

Comment: @makerofthings: Go for it! I already do this occasionally - but this only makes sense if they didnt already get more answers there than they would here...

Answer (score 5):

I say to leave them there. Over time people will decide what questions they want to ask here and what questions on stackoverflow. If this site becomes enough of a "hub" for security experts, then the SO community will start self-moderating to recommend security questions come here anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, better would if all security related questions are gathered in one place - here. But doubling them could bring some disorder. Ideal solution would be just to move them here and maybe leave notice about this replacement on the place of previous topic. 
Simply, there are big chances that those question will be asked again here, because not all users are aware of those answers existence in some other place.

Comment: Yes, but what happens if a typical programmer, an SO user, does a search over there? Answers here wont turn up...

Comment: do we have stats on how folks search - do they just use google, or grab the search within SO? I know I use internet-wide google first, then narrow down.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there are duplicates, I'm sure the tone and response will be geared for this specific community as it grows.  I'll find the different perspectives educational, just as I currently do when I compare the overlap in the existing sites.

Answer (score 1):

I think migrating the core ones over is appropriate now, and will have the added benefit of driving more traffic this way.

By core ones, I mean those which absolutely sit in the remit for security stackexchange.

For other ones which perhaps don't have so many answers in SO I think we can all keep adding comments suggesting individuals re-ask their question here.

Comment: Questions that are very much within the domain of the other site, e.g. secure coding on SO, that also got a lot of answers there - migrating them here just feels greedy.

Comment: That said, if you see a question that really *should* be here and not there, and/or did not get a lot of answers there - feel free to get the mods over there to migrate it here. Either grab the mod in Teacher's Lounge, or even flag the q for moderator directly. Most of them are happy to ship over q's, especially ones that are borderline ontopic there, or didnt get enough answers...

Comment: Oooh - teacher's lounge. Cool. +1